# how to Replace column values with several conditions

Tags: python, pandas, replace, conditional-statements

I have a column as follows:

```
     A          B
0    0      20.00
1    1      35.00
2    2      75.00
3    3      29.00
4    4     125.00
5    5      16.00
6    6      52.50
7    7        NaN
8    8        NaN
9    9        NaN
10  10        NaN
11  11        NaN
12  12        NaN
13  13     239.91
14  14      22.87
15  15      52.74
16  16      37.20
17  17      27.44
18  18      57.01
19  19      29.88
```

I want to change the values of the column as follows
if `0<B<10.0`, then Replace the cell value of B by "0 to 10"
if `10.1<B<20.0`, then Replace the cell value of B by "10 to 20"
continue like this until the maximum range achieved.
I have tried

```
ds['B'] = np.where(ds['B'].between(10.0,20.0), "10 to 20", ds['B'])
```

But once I perform this operation, the DataFrame is occupied by the string `"10 to 20"` so I cannot perform this operation again for the remaining values of the DataFrame. After this step, the DataFrame looks like this:

```
     A         B
0    0  10 to 20
1    1      35.0
2    2      75.0
3    3      29.0
4    4     125.0
5    5  10 to 20
6    6      52.5
7    7       nan
8    8       nan
9    9       nan
10  10       nan
11  11       nan
12  12       nan
13  13    239.91
14  14     22.87
15  15     52.74
16  16      37.2
17  17     27.44
18  18     57.01
19  19     29.88
```

And the following line: `ds['B'] = np.where(ds['B'].between(20.0,30.0), "20 to 30", ds['B'])` will throw `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`

How can i code this to change all of the values in the DataFrame to these strings of ranges all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom function that maps each range to a string. For example, 19.0 will be mapped to "10 to 20", and then apply this function to each row.

I've written the code so that the minimum and maximum of the range is generalizable to the DataFrame, and takes on values that are multiples of 10.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## copy and paste your DataFrame
ds = pd.read_clipboard()

# floor to nearest multiple of 10
ds_min = ds['B'].min()//10*10
# ceiling to the nearest multiple of 10
ds_max = round(ds['B'].max(),-1)

ranges = np.linspace(ds_min, ds_max, ((ds_max-ds_min)/10)+1)

def map_value_to_string(value):
    for idx in range(1,len(ranges)):
        low_value, high_value = ranges[idx-1], ranges[idx]
        if low_value < value <= high_value:
            return f"{int(low_value)} to {int(high_value)}"
        else:
            continue

ds['B'] = ds['B'].apply(lambda x: map_value_to_string(x))
```

Output:

```
>>> ds
     A           B
0    0    10 to 20
1    1    30 to 40
2    2    70 to 80
3    3    20 to 30
4    4  120 to 130
5    5    10 to 20
6    6    50 to 60
7    7        None
8    8        None
9    9        None
10  10        None
11  11        None
12  12        None
13  13  230 to 240
14  14    20 to 30
15  15    50 to 60
16  16    30 to 40
17  17    20 to 30
18  18    50 to 60
19  19    20 to 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Build your bins and labels and use `pd.cut`:

```
bins = np.arange(0, df["B"].max() // 10 * 10 + 10, 10).astype(int)
labels = [' to '.join(t) for t in zip(bins[:-1].astype(str), bins[1:].astype(str))]

df["B"] = pd.cut(df["B"], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

```
>>> df
     A           B
0    0    10 to 20
1    1    30 to 40
2    2    70 to 80
3    3    20 to 30
4    4  120 to 130
5    5    10 to 20
6    6    50 to 60
7    7         NaN
8    8         NaN
9    9         NaN
10  10         NaN
11  11         NaN
12  12         NaN
13  13         NaN
14  14    20 to 30
15  15    50 to 60
16  16    30 to 40
17  17    20 to 30
18  18    50 to 60
19  19    20 to 30
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with much less code as this is actually just a matter of string formatting.

```
ds['B'] = ds['B'].apply(lambda x: f'{int(x/10) if x>=10 else ""}0 to {int(x/10)+1}0' if pd.notnull(x) else x)
```